# Install unregistered crate with cargo

Tags: rust, package, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have a crate (https://github.com/wilbertom/bichannels) that is not registered on crates.io. I would like to add it to my current crate, as a dependency. I've tried going into its directory (placed inside the outer crate) and running `cargo install`, but that doesn't work, instead, giving this error:

```
error: no packages found with binaries or examples
```

So it appears that one can only install a binary crate, but how do I add a library crate to my dependencies? I've tried adding:

```
bichannels = "*"
```

to my Cargo.toml but that just says that this package is not on crates.io.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

add this to Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
"bichannels" = {git = "https://github.com/wilbertom/bichannels"}
```

Or git clone locally the lib and use:

```
[dependencies]
"bichannels" = {path = "<roor_dir_of_your_clone>"}
```