# How to install rust crate?

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-crates

Basically I want to install a different version of a crate that I found in [GitHub](https://github.com/morteham/feos/tree/saftvrqmie), currently unregistered, I'm really new to Rust so maybe there is something that I'm missing. I've already [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985349/install-unregistered-crate-with-cargo) and that didn't work.

The instructions says that to install the package directly into the active environment I need to run `maturin develop --release --features "python all_models"`, but when I do that my terminal doesn't do anything, it feels like its loading something but doesn't.
I'm doing this in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with Python 3.10.6, pip 22.0.2, curl 7.81.0, rustc 1.64.0 and maturin 0.13.7 with pyo3-pack-0.6.1.

Does anyone know how to install an unregistered crate? using directly `cargo 'install'` didn't work since it's not a binary crate and gave me the error `no packages found with binaries or examples`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```ini
feos = { git = "https://github.com/morteham/feos/", branch = "saftvrqmie" }
```

in your `Cargo.toml` to use this fork of FeOS instead of the mainline `crates.io` version. The commands you're running have to do with building it from source which you don't have to do yourself if you're not developing on it and just using it instead.

I suspect it is the exclusion of the `branch` option which caused some confusion with the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985349/install-unregistered-crate-with-cargo) you looked into.